# What is telephone-number cash sums?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> At times the relentless repetition of **telephone-number cash sums** is overwhelming, but the overarching point is well made: we are in serious debt to the Earth.

What is telephone-number cash sums?

Source:[theguardian](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2013/jan/19/what-has-nature-ever-done-for-us-tony-juniper-review)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context mentioned, the phrase refers to amounts of money that have 7-10 digits, i.e. telephone numbers.  In other words, between 1 million and 10 billion (dollars.)

Comment: I had never heard the term, but that's what I'd have come up with. Consider that I just checked and according to demonocracy.info, The U.S. government spends $7,264,020 per minute. In the U.S. a local phone number might look like '726-4020' and you can imagine that looking at what is spent per month or year, or our national debt would easily correspond to a full phone number like 18,887,264,020 : 1-888-726-4020

Comment: I imagine the phrase alludes to sums of money that are suitably large (for the sake of the argument) rather than having specifically 7-10 digits; in other words, a figure of speech.